# Show that $((\phi → \psi)→((\psi→\chi)→(\phi→\chi)))$ is a Theorem of L.

Tags: logic

Show that $((\phi → \psi)→((\psi→\chi)→(\phi→\chi)))$ is a Theorem of L.

I a previous part of the Q i am asked to state the deduction theorem so I assume i have to use this and the axioms A1, A2, A3, and also Modus Ponens to prove that the formula is a theorem of L.

I am really struggling with doing any question using the axioms to show something is a theorem of L. I can almost work my way through an example, but even then I am confused with why / how certain steps are done.

Could you help me work through this.
Thanks

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you reveal to us what L, A1, A2, and A3 are. These names are not standard, but must be specific to the particular text you're working from.

Answer (score 4):

If you are allowed to appeal to the deduction theorem then this is very easy, and indeed you don't need to make further appeal to any of the axioms (so it just happens that this question can be answered even though you haven't told us which particular axioms A1, A2, A3 in fact are).

For you can show

$$\varphi, (\varphi \to \psi), (\psi \to \chi) \vdash_L \chi$$

using modus ponens twice (OK?). Then one application of the deduction theorem gives you

$$(\varphi \to \psi), (\psi \to \chi) \vdash_L (\varphi \to \chi)$$

(OK?) and a second application gives you

$$(\varphi \to \psi) \vdash_L ((\psi \to \chi) \to (\varphi \to \chi))$$

(OK?). And then what happens if you use the deduction theorem again?

Comment: I sort of can see where the deduction theorem has been used, but can you explain why you have started with what you have and what that exactly is, i don't understand the commas..

Comment: That's just a list of three premises, separated by commas. But your even asking that suggests you need to do some serious homework, with a textbook or three in the library!

Comment: i do, i really cannot get my head around this sort of question. I'm finding text books no help.

Comment: could you explain the steps?

Comment: @ZZS14 - as per answer of Peter Smith, in this case you do not need axioms (A1)-(A3) [I suspect they are those of Elliott Mendelson, *Introduction to mathematical logic* (4ed - 1997)] but of course you have used them (more precisely : (A1) and (A2) to prove the *Deduction Theorem*). You need aslo to "master" the concept pf *deduction* form *assumptions* : $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$ : you apply it in the *DT* to get from $\Gamma \cup \{ A \} \vdash B$ to $\Gamma \vdash $A \rightarrow B$. 1/2

Comment: @ZZS14 - having said that, you proceed as follows; assume the set $\Gamma$ of assumptions : $φ,(φ→ψ),(ψ→χ)$; from $φ$ and $(φ→ψ)$, apply *modus ponens* and get $ψ$; from $ψ$ and $(ψ→χ)$, apply *mp* again, to get $χ$. Now uou have a *deduction* of $χ$ form *assumptions* $φ,(φ→ψ),(ψ→χ)$, i.e. $φ,(φ→ψ),(ψ→χ) \vdash χ$. Apply *DT* once and get : $(φ→ψ),(ψ→χ) \vdash (φ→χ)$; apply *DT* to get $(φ→ψ) \vdash ((ψ→χ)→(φ→χ))$. Finally, apply *DT* a third time and you will have : $\vdash (φ→ψ) → ((ψ→χ)→(φ→χ))$.

Comment: i understand once you use the deduction theorem but i am confused by what you start with and why

Comment: @ZZS14 - but the starting point is : what is your textbook ? What have you already studied ? **If** you know the definition of *deduction* from *assumptions*, then our set $\Gamma$ of assumption is the set $\{ φ,(φ→ψ),(ψ→χ) \}$. Form this set we derive $χ$ [see PS's answer]; thus, we have $\{ φ,(φ→ψ),(ψ→χ) \} \vdash χ$. Now we apply *DT* : from $\Gamma \cup \{ A \} ⊢ B$ to $\Gamma \vdash A \rightarrow B$, with $φ$ as $A$ and $χ$ as $B$ to get : $\{ (φ→ψ),(ψ→χ) \} \vdash φ \rightarrow χ$. And so on ...

Comment: I've studied a logic course, but it wasn't very well lectured and now the exam in 1st May. I know the definition of what is meant by saying there is a deduction of $\psi$ from $\gamma$? I just don't understand the first step before the use of the deduction theorem

Comment: @ZZS14 - Please, review Peter Smith's answer: he starts from the set $\{ φ,(φ→ψ),(ψ→χ) \}$ of assumptions and pick up the first two : $φ$ and $(φ→ψ)$ in order to apply *mp*; in this way, he derives $ψ$. Then he uses it with the third assumption : $(ψ→χ)$; again, by *mp* he derives $χ$ , and it's done.

Answer (score 0):

So, let's look at "((ϕ→ψ)→((ψ→χ)→(ϕ→χ)))".  It is a conditional.  What is it's antecedent?  (ϕ→ψ).  What is it's consequent?  ((ψ→χ)→(ϕ→χ)).  Thus, if we have the deduction (meta) theorem, if we assume (ϕ→ψ) and can derive ((ψ→χ)→(ϕ→χ)), we can then use the proof procedure outlined by the proof of the deduction theorem to get to ((ϕ→ψ)→((ψ→χ)→(ϕ→χ))).  But, how do we get ((ψ→χ)→(ϕ→χ))?  Well, what is the primary connective for ((ψ→χ)→(ϕ→χ))?  A conditional.  So, what's the antecedent?  (ψ→χ).  What's the consequent?  (ϕ→χ).  Thus, if we can assume (ψ→χ) and derive (ϕ→χ), then we can infer  ((ψ→χ)→(ϕ→χ)) by the derivable rule of conditional introduction, which follows from the deduction theorem.  Note that when trying to prove ((ψ→χ)→(ϕ→χ)), we still had the assumption (ϕ→ψ) in place.  How do we derive (ϕ→χ)?  Well, could we assume the antecedent ϕ and deduce the consequent χ?  In other words... can we do this...

```
  1 |   (ϕ→ψ) assumption
  2 ||  (ψ→χ) assumption
  3 ||| ϕ     assumption
  .
  .
  .
  x ||| χ     ?
```

Comment: This looks dangerously close to confusing the Deduction Theorem, a meta-level theorem about a Hilbert-style proofs system, with Conditional Proof as a rule inside a natural deduction system allowing the making and discharge of temporary assumptions.

Comment: @PeterSmith If we have the deduction theorem, then conditional proof is a derivable rule of inference for a Hilbert system.

Comment: It is rather more delicate an issue than that. What is true is that you can conservatively extended a Hilbert system into a mixed system which allow the making and discharge of temporary assumptions. But that's to introduce a proof-system of a new character, and we are no longer inside e.g. The Mendelson system I guess the OP is using.

Comment: @PeterSmith How is it a more delicate issue?  How is it a proof system of a new character?  The relevant subsystem under detachment probably is either {CpCqp, CCpCqrCCpqCpr} or {CpCqp, CCpqCCpCqrCpr} both of which have the same theorems [both axiom sets imply the deduction meta theorem, and if you have the deduction meta theorem, then you have the law of commutation which makes the axiom sets interderivable).  The extension here doesn't introduce any new theorems nor remove any theorems.  So, how have we stepped outside of the original system?

Comment: The mixed system allows the temporary introduction of new assumptions; a Frege-Hilbert system doesn't, by definition.